# Connect only once for all queries in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I have an MSSQL database on a remote server. SSMS 2012 asks me to connect every time I double click a query in "Solution Explorer" in my project despite all of them having the same connection. Also, when I open the project - it asks me for every query that's already "open".

Is it supposed to work like this? If so - Any way around this?

Another thing: When SSMS opens - it doesn't have the passwords there. When I double click a query - it does. Is it supposed to be like this?

(I asked a similar question, but had a mistake. Also, added some information here...)

Comment: I've seen the multi-auth prompts when the queries are opened from a zip file as opposed to unzipped 1st. Sounds like that's probably not the case from what you've described, but thought I'd mention it.